# .filter function "is not a function" error

Tags: json, reactjs, filter, redux

i'm having a little problem here. I have a json file like this:

```
[
 {
"lang": "en",
    "page": {
      "menu": {
        "home": "Home",
        "about": "About"
},
....
]
```

and by default i want to load my main page with the english language so i create a function like this:

```
import content from '../data/content.json';

    let api = {
      getContent(language = 'en') {
        return content.filter(obj => obj.lang === language)[0];
      }
    };
    export default api;
```

An error is appeared in the console: Uncaught TypeError: _content2.default.filter is not a function Do you have any idea what's goin on?

Comment: Here it worked.... How is your project folder structured?

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON file doesn't export anything, that's why. You could export your object from `content.js` file instead:

```
export default [
  {
    "lang": "en",
    "page": {
      "menu": {
        "home": "Home",
        "about": "About"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and

```
import content from '../data/content.js';
```

Comment: i added an export default like your suggestion but the same error is apppearing

Comment: It was life saving answer. Thanks.